# Why doesn't setTimeout() work in my sorting function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, while-loop, settimeout

**UPDATE**
I could not figure out what the problem was to this, but I found a solution to my overall problem. I simply changed my bubbleSort() algorithm to only utilize for-loops and that appeared to work. Thank you for the help!

I am currently learning javaScript and React. As a practice project, I am attempting to create a sorting algorithm visualizer. For a (what I thought would be a simple) warmup, I have implemented bubble sort first, using a psuedocode I found online. I had it so the array sorts and changes on screen, but it was too fast so it didn't show the actual animation for the process on how it got to that point. In order to do that I would need to delay each iteration of the loops in the algorithm. However, my implementation is acting strange. The display animates the first iteration being sorted, then suddenly stops. The algorithm seems to quit early instead of finish the whole process when I add setTimeout() to my function. To finish the whole sorting process you need to repeatedly press the button until every single item is sorted. Nothing I try seems to work, and I would be very grateful if anyone could explain why and maybe offer some help.

```
bubbleSort() {
        var arr = this.state.array
        var isSorted = false
        var lastUnsorted = arr.length - 1
        while (!isSorted) {
            isSorted = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < lastUnsorted; ++i) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                        swap(arr, i, i + 1)
                        isSorted = false
                    }
                    this.setState({ array: arr })
                }, i * 1);
            }
            lastUnsorted--
        }
        this.setState({ array: arr })
    }
```

Comment: The delay parameter of `setTimeout` is the amount of milliseconds, so you'll probably want to increase that factor of 1 to something like 500 or 1000. In addition, `setTimeout` doesn't pause execution, it'll run the code inside the callback asynchronously, in parallel.

Comment: Hey Bryan, you might wanna consider using a function calls itself until it's sorted and you can call functions with `setTimeout` maybe? I'm not sure how it will work with React and states and such but worth the shot i guess =)

Comment: this is because delayed functions was not run and none of them cleared `isSorted` flag in a loop - stays true, while loop breakes.... you can do this animation using variables in state, no local variables ... each iteration follow with delayed check `if( ! this.state.isSorted ) this.repeatLoop()`

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, but your code doesn't wait for it to resolve, so it calls `setTimeout` for `lastUnsorted` times, so all the timeouts happen at the same time.

You need to controll it with callbacks.

The setup below will cause the console.log('tick') to happen every 1 second for 5 seconds.

```js
const functionToRepeat = () => {
  console.log('tick')
}

const loopWithCallback = (callback, i, limit) => {
  if(i > limit) return
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    callback(loopWithCallback(callback, i+1, limit))
  }, 1000)
  
}

loopWithCallback(functionToRepeat, 1, 5)
```